# Setting nodata from no polygon

Tags: polygon, rasterization, nodata

I am trying to convert polygon to raster. The polygon class are from 0 to 4. There are many spot that no polygon. It means, I don't create polygon. I try use QGIS, using Raster > Conversion > Rasterize. The result is 0 to 4, but the spot with no polygon is also 0. How to set no polygon to nodata like in :
https://github.com/remicres/otbtf_tutorials_resources/blob/master/01_patch_based_classification/tokyo_dataset/terrain_truth/terrain_truth_epsg32654_A.tif

How can I create that using open source software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an output nodata value that is something other than 0-4 as the default is 0.
See the [help](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster) for the NoData parameter:

> Assign a specified nodata value to output bands Default: 0.0

Comment: Ok I set nodata value other than 0-4. I set 100. Thanks. It is work